# Using 'place that' instead of 'place where'

Tags: relative-clauses, that, where

*Practical English Usage*, Fourth Edition (Fully Revised International Edition), by Michael Swan has this sentence under subsection **237 relatives: advanced points**:

> *We need a place (that) we can stay for a few days.* (<sub><sup>BUT NOT</sup></sub> <del>*We need a house we can stay for a few days.*</del>)

What PEU is saying here is that relative adverb *where* after *place* can be replaced by *that* or dropped in an informal style.

But *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 1053) by H&P begs to differ:

> Relatives introduced by *where*, by contrast, do not in general alternate with the non-*wh* type except where the antecedent is a very general noun such as *place*:
>
> [61] i *This is much better than the hotel* [***where** we stayed last year*].
>
> ii *This is much better than the place* [***where***/(<sup>?</sup>***that***) *we stayed last year*].
>
> The ‘<sup>?</sup>’ annotation in [ii] applies to the version with *that* (<sup>?</sup>*the place that we stayed last year*); the bare relative (*the place we stayed last year*) is more acceptable.

In CGEL, the ‘<sup>?</sup>’ annotation means that the sentence is of questionable grammaticality. That is, CGEL is saying that sentence [ii] with *that* is of questionable grammaticality, whereas PEU is saying that the quoted sentence with *that* is grammatical.

Are both PEU and CGEL right about the use of *that* in their sentences? If so, how can we distinguish between the two sentences? If not, is PEU or CGEL wrong about the use of *that* in their sentences?

Comment: Attempting to close the question while failing to leave a single comment is just beyond me.

Comment: I would say "The place [that] we stayed **in** or **at**. Otherwise it sounds odd to me, since _place_ isn't the direct object of _stay_.

Comment: One source says questionable, the other says only in informal style. What's the difference? They seem to agree as far as I can tell. Are you looking for further authoritative sources that comment on this question, or usage examples maybe from respected publications? Otherwise, this will run into the realm of opinion.

Comment: @DW256 In general, I don't think you should conflate "informal" and "of questionable grammaticality". In CGEL, specifically, they have many examples that they treat as "informal", but none of the informal examples receives the '?' annotation. Also, none of the examples receives the '?' annotation in CGEL simply because they're informal. Moreover, PEU treats both the _that_ version and the bare version as "informal", but CGEL puts the '?' annotation only on the _that_ version.

Comment: Informal means the way people talk most of the time. Formal means when they're reading aloud; it's for writing, not talking. Questionable means possibly ungrammatical, i.e, grammatical for some people but ungrammatical for others.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for clarifying that. The two concepts should never be confused or conflated.

Comment: Many people get confused about when they should use "where" versus "that" in phrases like this.

Comment: @KateBunting So do you think PEU is wrong?

Comment: @Barmar That's assuming that using _that_ is wrong. If either is fine, it's not really getting confused. For example, after _time_, you can use either _when_ or _that_ or nothing: _Come and see us any time when/(that) you’re in town._ Here, you're not going to say people get confused about when they should use "when" versus "that", are you?

Comment: @JK2 In the cases where one is preferred they get confused, probably because of all the cases where either is OK.

Comment: @Barmar Which do you mean? That people get confused so much that using _that_ in the OP became grammatical (descriptively, that is), or that using _that_ in the OP is still unidiomatic despite apparent usage by confused people.

Comment: PEU is probably correct that some people say that, but I wouldn't.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you find both _the place that we stayed last year_ and _the place we stayed last year_ odd? Or, do you find only the former odd? Also, how about _a place that we can relax_ (without any preposition)?

Comment: I think I would always say either _the place where we stayed_ or _the place [that] we stayed at_. _A place that we can relax_ sounds to me as though you are talking about relaxing the place, though I expect that some people would say it.

Comment: @JK2 There's probably some of both, but I think the second is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

**I**

> In CGEL, the ‘?’ annotation means that the sentence is of questionable grammaticality. That is, CGEL is saying that sentence [ii] with *that* is of questionable grammaticality, whereas PEU is saying that the quoted sentence with *that* is grammatical.

The problem stems from the various points of view held in these sources. First, usage and grammar are not the same thing, even if while doing grammar an author will also consider usage.

> ([Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/usage/grammar-usage/#:%7E:text=In%20linguistics%2C%20the%20term%20usage%20relates%20to%20the,sentences%2C%20and%20how%20words%20combine%20to%20make%20sentences.)) In linguistics, the term *usage* relates to the habits of language use among a
> language’s native speakers, particularly with regard to the meanings of words and phrases. Grammar relates to the functions of words, the construction of sentences, and how words combine to make sentences. Usage evolves continually, often rapidly, and is subjective in many ways. Grammar is more rule-based and objective and tends to evolve more slowly. The two subjects are often lumped together, usually under the term grammar, but for people who study and teach about them, they warrant very different approaches.

PEU is concerned essentially with usage, as the title suggests, whereas CGEL has a strictly grammatical point of view. There is yet another criterion a grammarian may refer to, and this one is *user acceptability*. The fact that native users are not sure about acceptability is symbolized by "?" in CoGEL; there are therefore two important types of usage: widely accepted usage and usage that is still open to question by a significant proportion of the users (let's call it "unsure usage" for the sake of referring to it).  It is such usage  that might be characterized by such comments  as the one made above by **[user Kate Bunting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593418/using-place-that-instead-of-place-where#comment1491457_593418)** (I would say "The place [that] we stayed in or at. Otherwise it sounds odd to me, since *place* isn't the direct object of *stay*.). Here is what the grammarians who wrote CoGEL have to say about the use of relatives in the present context (note that  the symbol "?"  concerns acceptability, more exactly, "unsure  acceptability").

> With a general antecedent, such as *place*, we may find the following patterns, which however are not acceptable to all speakers:
> • (?)That's *the place she stays when she's in London*. [1]
> • (?)That's *the place she works*. [2]
> • (?)That's *the place she studies*. [3]
>
> However, a final *at* […] would be fully acceptable, at least in familiar
> usage:
> • That's *the place she stays at when she's in London*.   [1a]
> • That's *the place she works at*. [2a]
> • That's *the place she studies at*. [3a]
>
> With a generalized antecedent such as *way*, expressing direction, we usually have zero rather than *that*:
>
> - Was that the way she went? ['Was that where she went?']

So, PEU is not  saying that  the sentence with "that" (only "that") is grammatical but  instead that it is fully acceptable and they stand in contradiction with CoGEL since the grammarians of   that latter grammar assert that this is not yet a  fully accepted construction.  CGEL is not  to  be  questioned  since they seem to place themselves  on the level of strict grammar and that the point that they would most certainly make (not a direct object) is correct.

**II**

> Are both PEU and CGEL right about the use of *that* in their sentences? If so, how can we distinguish between the two sentences? If not, is PEU or CGEL wrong about the use of that in their sentences?

Were they using one and the same criterion for determining idiomaticity, one of the two only can  be wrong, but one  of them must be. If it is PEU, this is so on the ground of the possible evidence that could be read in CGEL and CoGEL, the former only  contesting (rightly) grammaticality and therefore denying the possible reality of a usage tending towards acceptability  and the second  recognizing at most an unsure usage (and thereby acknowledging implicitly a breach of grammar). If it is CGEL, this is so on the ground of their failure  to evidence a  well accepted usage that makes of  such phrases as "place they  go" true  idioms of  the language. As it is likely that  there is no such common  criterion neither is right or wrong; what remains certain is that those forms  have gained in  acceptability to an important extent, as CoGEL acknowledges.

A  distinction as to register is a matter of personal choice for the time being,  but I feel that the impression of oddness  is  bound to surface one day or other in the  mind of  the reader that has  become sufficiently familiar with the language.

Comment: I'm also aware of CoGEL's treatment of the issue that you've cited. There, they have presented "Pattern 6: antecedent+ zero relative + zero preposition" and "Pattern 7: antecedent+ that+ zero preposition" in the previous page, but they only discussed Pattern 6 for the _place_ antecedent, which they say is "not acceptable to all speakers". But somehow they failed to discuss Pattern 7 for the _place_ antecedent, which is the issue of the OP.

Comment: And I think usage changes more rapidly in this type of grammar than others (e.g., article usage), and that CoGEL might be too old-fashioned to be reliable.

Comment: Also, A Student's Introduction to English Grammar (H&P's short version of CGEL) lists _a place that we can relax_ as a legitimate example. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

A few cursory searches in COCA seem to mostly favor the *where*-relatives over *that* when appearing with head noun *place*, and the version with nothing (-) over *that* in all cases.

> place * PRON LIVE .
>
> 2 that vs 33 where vs 27 (-)
>
> place * PRON STAY .
>
> 0 that vs 1 where vs 2 (-)
>
> place * PRON BE born .
>
> 0 that vs 27 where vs 5 (-)
>
> place * PRON SLEEP .
>
> 0 that vs 6 where vs 0 (-)
>
> place * PRON DIE .
>
> 0 that vs 7 where vs 3 (-)
>
> place * PRON GO .
>
> 6 that vs 3 where vs 40 (-)
>
> place * PRON WORK .
>
> 2 that vs 20 where vs 13 (-)
>
> place * PRON MEET .
>
> 0 that vs 2 where vs 1 (-)

Though far from exhaustive, the data above does support the CGEL view that *that* is less acceptable than nothing at all.